# Between a WordPress blog and a forum using Adsense, what do I need to do to make my website GDPR compliant?

Tags: gdpr

Firstly, I'm hoping this is the correct forum for this thread (I couldn't figure out which other section to post it in).

So I have a query about GDPR.

To make it as simple as possible, I have a website (blog on Wordpress) and a forum that has Google Adsense ads on them. Nothing else. What do I need to do to make sure my website is GDPR compliant?

Do I need to have a Privacy Policy on my website? A Cookie Policy on my website? An "accept" or " reject" pop-up on my website. Am I able to copy a default template from somewhere or install a relevant free plugin? Am I better paying for something for this?

I just want to make blog articles daily and have people post on my forum without having to worry about all this GDPR stuff.

I know with Google Adsense, you can turn on a GDPR message that I believe will display on my website for every visitor. Is this enough to make my website GDPR compliant or do I still need to do something else?

Thank you all.

Comment: In my experience, most sites have been using TrustArc or OneTrust for GDPR compliance.

Comment: Hi @CrayonViolent - I just checked those out and they seem more for large organizations. I'm just a one man band who runs a website + forum in my spare time lol. Do you know of any more?

Comment: I am not in EU, but GDPR has been around for a while now, surely there is some information out there on what is required.

Comment: @DannyM You mentioned using WordPress. A quick google shows there's a plugin that might look promising for you? https://wordpress.org/plugins/gdpr-cookie-compliance/

Comment: @CrayonViolent Thank you, this does seem like the best free Wordpress plugin. It's just a bit worry at the bottom of the plugin page, it says in all capitals: "THIS PLUGIN DOES NOT MAKE YOUR WEBSITE COMPLIANT. YOU ARE RESPONSIBLE FOR ENSURING THAT ALL COOKIE LAW REQUIREMENTS ARE MET ON YOUR WEBSITE."

Comment: Right. No different than Lowes (not) claiming responsibility for whatever you do with the toolset you bought from it. Or me taking responsibility for advice I give you here, lol. Ultimately it's on you to implement it correctly, etc. This is one of the many reasons why bigger companies have legal teams; to sort stuff like that out. As an individual person w/ a blog/forum and no resources like a bigger company.. you just roll the dice on stuff like that.